# Is the scipy.stats.ks_2samp function supposed to take in raw data arrays or the ECDF of the data?

Tags: python, scipy.stats, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm confused on how to use the scipy stat function ks_2samp. I have 2 samples of discrete data and want to see if they are significantly different. I have tried 3 things:

1. directly input the raw data
2. input the ecdfs of the data
3. input pdf fit of the data

I'm getting different values each time and I do not know which is the right one and the right method. From the [scipy.stats.ks_2samp documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html), it looks like *data1 and data2* are raw data samples. But the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) says that I need to input empirical data. I'm working with a huge dataset. Also, please suggest if there's any other method to achieve the same.

Following is my code snippet:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    import scipy.stats as ss 
    from scipy.stats import norm 
    import pandas as pd
        
    # x0 is a dataframe column
    
    mean0 = np.mean(x0) 
    std0 = np.std(x0) 
    pdf0 = ss.norm.pdf(x0.sort_values(), mean0, std0)
        
    mean1 = np.mean(x1) 
    std1 = np.std(x1) 
    pdf1 = ss.norm.pdf(x1.sort_values(), mean1, std1)
        
    def ecdf(x):
            xs = np.sort(x)
            ys = np.arange(1, len(xs)+1)/float(len(xs))
            return xs, ys
        
      
    xs0, ys0 = ecdf(x0) xs1, ys1 = ecdf(x0)
        
    rslt1=ss.ks_2samp(x0,x1) 
    rslt2=ss.ks_2samp(ys0,ys1) 
    rslt3=ss.ks_2samp(pdf0,pdf1)
        
        
    print(rslt1) 
    print(rslt2) 
    print(rslt3)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`scipy.stats.ks_2samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) accepts raw samples. You do not need to do any fitting, parametric or non-parametric (e.g. ecdf), beforehand. So #1 of the things you tried and `rslt1` of your code look valid.

One way you can confirm this is by repeatedly generating samples under the null hypothesis and checking the distribution of p-values. Roughly speaking, they should be uniformly distributed (although there are some footnotes in the case of this test due to the discrete nature of the statistic).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(459324692354693456)
pvals = []
for i in range(10000):
  x = rng.normal(size=500)
  y = rng.normal(size=500)
  res = stats.ks_2samp(x, y, method='asymp')
  pvals.append(res.pvalue)

res = stats.ecdf(pvals)
res.cdf.plot()
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.title("ECDF of p-values under H0")
plt.xlabel("p-value")
plt.ylabel("Empirical CDF")
plt.legend(["ECDF", "Expected"])
```

[image: ECDF of p-values under H0]

If you were to pre-process the data according to ideas #2 or #3, the distribution of p-values would not be as expected.

Other tests of the null hypothesis that the two samples were drawn from the same distribution are [`scipy.stats.cramervonmises_2samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cramervonmises_2samp.html), [`scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp.html#scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp), and [`scipy.stats.epps_singleton_2samp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.epps_singleton_2samp.html#scipy.stats.epps_singleton_2samp). The last two do not assume the underlying distribution is continuous.

There are many other [independent sample tests](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#independent-sample-tests) that may be more sensitive to specific deviations, but these are the ones that are most similar in usage to Kolmogorov-Smirnov.

Note that there is also a `scipy.stats.ecdf` as of SciPy 1.11.0, and if you know what distribution you want to fit, you can use the [distribution's `fit` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html) or [`scipy.stats.fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ecdf.html).